# Jenkins can not build with Maven. Might be proxy-issue

Tags: maven, proxy, jenkins, nexus

I'm trying to set-up a environment with Maven, Jenkins, SVN and Nexus. 
I added Jobs to Jenkins via SVN, but Jenkins can not build these Jobs due to a Maven error.

Here is the error-log

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building imagetools 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 21.756s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 22 11:43:05 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\franzm\.jenkins\jobs\ImageTools\workspace\pom.xml to C:\Users\franzm\.jenkins\jobs\ImageTools\modules\com.ee$imagetools\builds\2013-04-22_11-42-40\archive\com.ee\imagetools\1.0\imagetools-1.0.pom
Warte bis Jenkins die Datensammlung abgeschlossen hat
mavenExecutionResult exceptions not empty
message : Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
cause : Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
Stack trace : 
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:261)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:139)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:158)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:100)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:66)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:296)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:186)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:279)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:115)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:281)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:pom:2.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.resourceExists(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:597)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:577)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://repo.maven.apache.org refused
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:674)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.resourceExists(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:593)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    ... 13 more
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

If I build Jenkins with Maven via the command line, everything works. It downloads all dependencies from the Nexus. I also have to add a Proxy to Maven.

I downloaded the Config File Management Plug-In to add an own settings.xml for Maven:

```
 <mirror>  
 <id>nexus</id>  
 <url>http://mynexusadress.com:6060/nexus/content/groups/public</url> <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
```

The access to the proxy is configured in the Nexus config files.
(As said, using Maven locally works fine, it downloads all dependencies from the Nexus and uploads the build jar to it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, solved this problem, it is quite simple.
I just had to edit the settings.xml for Maven in my Jenkins-Directory. Thought this is done automatically.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this for hours. For those who landed up on this page via a search engine:

Make sure maven settings.xml is for the user that runs jenkins. On Linux boxes a user "jenkins" runs the jenkins app so

```
sudo su - jenkins
cd ~/.m2
vi settings.xml
```

(Yes, vi. Real men use vi.)

And then modify as per standard procedures for adding proxy

```
<settings>
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <id>example-proxy</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <host>proxy.example.com</host>
  <port>8080</port>
  <username>proxyuser</username>
  <password>somepassword</password>
  <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
 </proxies>
 .
 .
</settings>
```

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 1):

You should configure proxy in Jenkins as described [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130414055345/http://blogs.wandisco.com/2012/08/15/jenkins-configuring-proxy/).

Comment: I did this before. Installing plug-ins works fine with the proxy.

Comment: the link is dead so this answer is worthless now